# yield return null не продолжает работу корутины

Tags: c#, unity3d, ienumerator

Хочу сделать тряску камеры после убийства врага, но функция проходит цикл while 1 раз (не зависимо от времени) и бесконечно ожидает `yield return null`. Вот код корутины

```
    public IEnumerator ShakeCamera(float duration, float magnitude)
    {
        Vector3 originalpos = new Vector3(0,0,0);

        float elapsed=0.0f;

        while (elapsed<duration)
        {
            float x = Random.Range(-1f, 1f) * magnitude;
            float y = Random.Range(-1f, 1f) * magnitude;

            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y,0f);


            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            print(elapsed);

            yield return null;
        }
        transform.localPosition = originalpos;
    }
```

и код врага, вызывающий эту корутину

```
public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    health -= damage;
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        Object.Destroy(gameObject);
        StartCoroutine(CamShake.ShakeCamera(0.15f, 1f));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извините за беспокойство, камера не двигалась из-за пустой анимации на ней

Answer (score 0):

yield return null стоит в нужном месте, что бы продолжить после прохода текущей итерации цикла Update. У меня подобная проблема была, вызвана она уничтожением GameObject, в вашем случае в этой строке Object.Destroy(gameObject);
Но как решить эту проблему я не знаю, я просто переделал код и убрал у себя Destroy(gameObject);
P.S. В моей 2d игре CameraShake вызывается через анимацию

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Повторил глюк (Unity 19.4.14LTS):

```
Debug.Log("1");
float iceDuration = 0.5f;
Destroy(ice = Instantiate(Ice, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1.5f, transform.position.z), Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles)), iceDuration);
ice.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
Debug.Log("2");
yield return new WaitForSeconds(iceDuration*2f);
Debug.Log("3"+currentState);
if (currentState == allStates[IdleState])
{
    Run();
}
```

После любого использования Destroy (даже не текущего объекта) корутины не продолжаются. В моём примере "3" не появится никогда. Отсрочил всё нужное с использованием другой корутины:

```
    Debug.Log("1");
    float iceDuration = 0.5f;
    Idle();
    StartCoroutine(IdleStateRelease(iceDuration));

    Destroy(ice = Instantiate(Ice, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1.5f, transform.position.z), Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles)), iceDuration);
    ice.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    Debug.Log("2");
}

private IEnumerator IdleStateRelease(float iceDuration)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(iceDuration * 2f);
    Debug.Log("3" + currentState);
    if (currentState == allStates[IdleState])
    {
        Run();
    }
}
```